# Add to class value in ruby on rails data in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such code:

```
  def accum_search

    if params[:akbcap].present?
      akbcap_array = [12,18,19,20,25,30,35,36,38,40,41,42,44,45,46,47,50,52,53,54,55,56,58,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,68,69,70,71,72,74,75,77,80,85,88,90,91,92,95,98,100,102,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,170,180,185,190,192,200,210,220,225]
      min, max = params[:akbcap].split('-').map {|s| s.to_i }
      logger.warn("!@!!!!!!!!!!!! AAA !!!!!!!!!!")
      logger.warn(min)
      logger.warn(max)
      caprange = min...max
      sa = akbcap_array.select {|n| caprange.include? n }
      #@cross = OtherProductsCrossList.find(:all, :conditions => {:cross_value => 1})
      cap = "*"+params[:akbcap]+"*"
      sa.each do |s|
        logger.warn(s)
        @accums = Accumulator.by_capacity(s).by_size(params[:akbsize]).by_brand(params[:akbbrand])
      end
    else      
      @accums = Accumulator.by_capacity(50).by_size(params[:akbsize]).by_brand(params[:akbbrand])
    end
  end
```

As you see i have such part:

```
sa.each do |s|
            logger.warn(s)
            @accums = Accumulator.by_capacity(s).by_size(params[:akbsize]).by_brand(params[:akbbrand])
          end
```

but could i add on every iteration in @accums data from search? now it has last value(  I could done it via arrays... but how to do **via class-variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, initiate it before the loop and use the << operator to append. End with flatten to make it a single dimension array.

```
@accums = []
# ...
sa.each do |s|
  @accums << Accumulator.several_method_calls......
end
@accums.flatten!
```

or for compactness:

```
result = sa.map{|s| Accumulator.several_method_calls...... }.flatten
```